# Ubuntu in Virtual box is upgrading packages terribly slow

Tags: apt, kernel, virtualbox

I recently upgraded VirtualBox to version 6.1.

I have a few Ubuntu virtual machines. The host is Ubuntu 18.04 with btrfs filesystem with COW disabled on the directory where the machines are stored. The directory is stored on a HDD.

Since the ugrade to VB 6.1 `apt upgrade` started working incredibly slow. Especialy on unpacking `linux-headers` packages. It can take 20-30 minutes to unpack, and the HDD is working with a weird sound.

Is my HDD close to death, or `btrfs` is bad for this purpose?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It appeared that "Use host I/O cache" is disabled by default in VirtualBox 6.1.

It is located under Storage ->  Controller: SATA

I enabled it back and now machines run smoothly again.